# Is the solution to the following correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Graph the area that is bounded by $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{a}$

$y = +(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{x})^2 $

First we find the zeros:
$$\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{x} = 0 \iff x = a$$

Also $a$ cannot be negative so we take integral bounds of lower bound of 0 and upper bound of a.

$$\frac{S}{2} = \int_{0}^{a} (\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{x})^2dx = \int_{0}^a (a + x - 2 \sqrt{ax}) = a\cdot a + a^2/2 -2\sqrt{a}\cdot a^{3/2}\frac{2}{3}) = a^2(1 + 1/2 - 2\cdot a\cdot\frac{2}{3}) = a^2(3/2 - a\cdot\frac{4}{3})
$$

Mistakes:
$$\frac{S}{2} \text{would have to be only } S$$
$$ \text{The second last line should be:}a\cdot a + a^2/2 -2\sqrt{a}\cdot a^{3/2}\frac{2}{3} = a^2(3/2-4/3)$$

Comment: I guess there's a typo in the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, note that the graph of the function can only lie in the first quadrant. Hence what you marked $\frac S2$ would actually be just $S$.
Also note the calculation error in the second last line, $a^{\frac 12}.a^{\frac 32}=a^2$ and not $a^3$.

Comment: I see, but otherwise it is correct right ?

Comment: What is the typo in the second line, you mean the plus sign?

Comment: Oh I see, my bad

Comment: There is also a calculation error in the second last line. $\sqrt {a}.a^{\frac 32}=a^2$, not $a^3$. That is all.